# Cannot connect to VM: socket operation on nonsocket - configureBlocking

Tags: eclipse, java-8, jvm

when debugging my maven project on Eclipse Neon (Win10), this error appears:
Cannot connect to VM: socket operation on nonsocket - configureBlocking

My environment is: java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

Eclipse Neon (Win10 - 64bits)

This error only occurs in a test class, for debugging purposes inside a

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hello stackoverflow, help me please");
}
```

[image: Error when debugging my maven project on Eclipse Neon]

Comment: Are you doing a remote server debug?

Comment: No, it is locally, at home and without proxy....etc

Comment: @BicaBicudo, Did you solve this problem?

Comment: unfortunally no!

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this question, the same thing is happening with my Eclipse when I try to debug Cucumber's feature files.

For some people, adding the following line in the hosts file solved the problem:

localhost       127.0.0.1

ps.: hosts file is in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\